# How to chain a list of promises in RXJS?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, rxjs, rxjs5

How can i chain a list of promises in RXJS? Every promise needs to be executed when the previous is resolved (work todo is stateful).

The way i'm doing it now feels primitive:

```
const workTodo = []; // an array of work
const allWork = Observable.create(observer => {
  const next= () => {
    const currentTodo = workTodo.shift();
    if (currentTodo ) {
      doTodoAsync(currentTodo)
        .then(result => observer.onNext(result))
        .then(next);
    } else {
      observer.onCompleted();
    }
  };
  next();
});
```

I was thinking something like this:

```
const workTodo = []; // an array of work
const allWork = Observable
                  .fromArray(workTodo)
                  .flatMap(doTodoAsync);
```

But that basically executes all promises at once.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you were pretty close with your attempt.

You may either specify maximum concurrency of 1 for `.flatMap` like:

```
Observable.fromArray(workTodo)
 .flatMap(doTodoAsync, 1)
```

or equivalently use `.concatMap` instead of `.flatMap`:

```
Observable.fromArray(workTodo)
 .concatMap(doTodoAsync)
```

I would use `concatMap` as it feels more idiomatic.

**UPDATE:** [DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/Ijlj4mXjrSO2sjoZvTqh?p=preview)

Comment: I've tested `concatMap`, but it seems to do something slightly different. It executes `doTodoAsync` in parallel and then combines the results in the original order. Also described here: http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/flatmap.html. The second parameter on flatMap as a `number` doesn't seem to exist.

Comment: @nicojs not sure what you exactly mean. Updated the answer with a running demo. It clearly shows that tasks are executed one after another and that `mergeMap/flatMap` accepts `concurrency` parameter as documented here: http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-mergeMap.

Answer (score 0):

How about some recursion?

First create a recursive function and call it `recursiveDoToDo`:

```
const recursiveDoToDo = (currentTodo, index) =>
    Observable
        .fromPromise(doTodoAsync(currentTodo))
        .map(resolved => ({resolved, index}));
```

The code above simply wraps your `doTodoAsync` into an Observable, and then we map the results to return the resolved promise **and** the `index` of the array, for recursion use later.

Next, we will recursively call the `recursiveDoToDo` with the [`.expand()`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-expand) operator.

```
recursiveDoToDo(worktodo[0], 0)
    .expand(res => recursiveDoToDo(worktodo[res.index + 1], res.index + 1))
    .take(worktodo.length)
```

All you need to do for your recursion is just to increment the index by 1. Because `.expand()` will recursively run forever, the `.take()` operator is there to tell the observable when to end the stream, which is the length of your `worktodo`.

Now you can simply subscribe to it:

```
recursion.subscribe(x => console.log(x));
```

Here is the [working JS Bin](https://jsbin.com/zulunogeta/1/edit?js,console)

Comment: It seems to work, but it also seems primitive. I think i like my recursive call better. I feel like there should be a simple operator to do this.